# MongoDB: Order of Chunk Migration

Tags: mongodb, sharding, chunks

i cannot find anything in the MongoDB documentation about that, therefore I'm trying to ask the experts :-)

In which order are chunks migrated between shards?

- Is it done randomly
- Is the chunk with the most actual creation date moved first from the source Shard to the target shard?

Thx for your help!